# debugging: i don't know where to fix my PHP code, there isn't an error and it isn't working

Tags: php, debugging

So i've been working on a social media site, and right now i'm making the registering portion of the site and this is what i have so far.  It would be extremely helpful because i have just started learning PHP a little bit ago, and I don't know where to go from here since it does not result in a error.

> 

```
if(isset($_POST['create-account'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    DB::query('INSERT INTO users VALUES (\'\',:username,: password, :email)'. array(':username'=>$username, ':password'=>$password,':email'=>$email));
    echo 'succsessfull';
}
?>
<h1>Register</h1>
<form action="create-account.php" method='post'>
    <input type='text' name='username' value='' placeholder="Username..."><p />
    <input type='password' name='password' value='' placeholder="Password..."><p />
    <input type='email' name='email' value='' placeholder="Email..."><p />
    <input type='submit' name='createaccount' value='submit'>
</form>
```

i also have a file called DB(data base) and the code for that is, and thank you for helping me with my problem:

```
    <?php
class DB{
    private static function connect(){
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=mysocial;charset=utf8;', 'root', '');
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDo::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return $pdo;
    }

    public static function query($query, $params = array()){
        $statement = self::connect()->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute($params);
        //$data = $statement->fetchAll();
        //return $data;
    }
}
?>
```

i don't know what else to say about my problem, besides hopefully i can finish this project

Comment: Did you notice the space character in your query near the `: password` placeholder? Also I think you want a space here: `:email)'` like this `:email) '` or it will result in `:email):username'` (no space)

Comment: yeah, i noticed a few smaller things like that and fixed them but it still doesn't work and there isn't an error

Comment: Try this: `try { DB::query(' .. ') catch(PDOException $e){ echo $e->getMessage(); }` - Replace DB:query with your actual query of course.

Comment: i tried that, and it's still doing the same thing...i'm starting to lose hope on this project

Comment: Wait. You are using a dot (.) in your query instead of a comma. `:email)'. array`. Instead of sending it as a parameter, you're doing string concetanation in the query

Comment: i also fixed that while looking through it for the 5th time and again, it doesn't work

Comment: Then I'm afraid there isn't much else I can do without looking at it myself.

Comment: `PDo::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` should be `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` that is a case sensitive.

Comment: Voted to close as a Simply Typographical Error judging by OP's own answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

so basically i was a dumb, and when it said

> if(isset($_POST[create-account])){

i should have put createaccount instead of create-account

Comment: glad you found it. at times like you're having i 'hose it down' with lots of var_dump calls to see what's going on.  var_dump($_POST) shows the error clearly.  also observe you didn't see 'successful' print out :)

Comment: Great. I would suggest deleting your question though. This falls under "A simple typographical error" here on Stack Overflow. It's not usefull to anyone in the future and will most likely get closed by the community anyway.

Answer (score 1):

#### Quick fix

```
<?php

// createaccount and not create-account
if(isset($_POST['createaccount'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    
    $query = "INSERT INTO users VALUES (null,:username,:password, :email)";
    $params =  array(
                ':username'=>$username, 
                ':password'=>$password,
                ':email'=>$email 
    );
    
    // you had extra parenthesis at the end here. Keep your code clean, make it easier to read
   // DB::query()'. array(':username'=>$username, ':password'=>$password,':email'=>$email));
   
    if( DB::query( $query, $params ) )
    {
        echo 'succsessfull';
    }
    else {
        echo 'Failed';
    }
}

?>
<h1>Register</h1>
<form action="create-account.php" method='post'>
    <input type='text' name='username' value='' placeholder="Username..."><p />
    <input type='password' name='password' value='' placeholder="Password..."><p />
    <input type='email' name='email' value='' placeholder="Email..."><p />
    <input type='submit' name='createaccount' value='submit'>
</form>
```

Comment: Don't just copy OP's own answer to grab a few points. You shouldn't answer Simple Typographical Errors in the first place either.

Comment: @icecub why would I copied OP answer? you should check how many seconds between when both answers were posted, I didn't see his answer until I posted mine, as you can see it cannot type all that within seconds.

Comment: You couldn't have known the problem was `$_POST['create-account']` without reading his answer. And even if that happened by some weird coincidence, it's still a Simple Typographical Error. Which means the question should be closed and NOT answered because that makes it a lot harder to close the question correctly.

Comment: Wait. You could've known that. My appologies. But still, don't answer typo questions. They're not usefull to future readers at all and only take up unnessesary space on SO. That's why they are closed instead.

Comment: @icecub When you are testing for a ***submitted data***, you should take a minute to `print_r( $the_submitted_data)` to know and see what you are working with, not just guessing the answers, unless you don't know what you are dong.  like when i pointed out the `PDO` was written `PDo`  do you think `PDO` is the same as `PDo` ?